# Maya import and read json file and extract data

Tags: json, python-3.x, maya

This is a json file called cube.json

```
  {
    "0": {
        "name": "pCube3",
        "data": {
            "1": {
                "0": [-0.120863, 0.162588, 0.357396],
                "1": [-0.0200321, 0.0269478, 0.0592358],
                "2": [-2.63913, 2.43487, 3.13613],
                "3": [-0.251917, 0.323026, 0.678479],
                "4": [-0.101669, 0.136768, 0.300639],
                "5": [-0.0148588, 0.0199885, 0.0439381],
                "6": [-0.00304363, 0.00409438, 0.00900015],
                "7": [0, 0, 0]
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

In Maya 2022 this is exported data of a blendshape. The 0-7 numbers are vertices number and the following numbers are x, y, and z translations. Is there a way to parse out the data separate the x , y , z transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python:

```
data = json.load("cube.json")

coords = []
values = data['0']['data']['1']
for k in values:
    coords.append(values[k])

print(coords)
```

result:

```
[[-0.120863, 0.162588, 0.357396], [-0.0200321, 0.0269478, 0.0592358], ...
```